# Why does sorting a column of emails not show duplicates under each other?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to flag duplicate email addresses in a Google Sheet column. I can't use the "remove duplicate" feature cause I need to flag them, not delete them.

When I use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates and then sort the column, I notice that duplicate emails do not appear under each other.

I used conditional formatting with this custom formula "=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10, A2)>=2"

But I have two issues with it:

1. When I sort the column of emails from A to Z, some highlighted values (duplicates), do not appear under each other. I don't understand how this is possible since only 1 sort is being applied.
2. The formula only highlights the duplicated value, not the "original value" (that is being duplicated)

Ex. If my column contains "email@email.com" and "email@email.com", only one of these will be highlighted. I need both to be highlighted.

I'll include a screenshot to clarify this further:
As you can see, only one of the duplicates is highlighted + a single value is highlighted, letting me think that the duplicate for "8293227@gmail.com" might be elsewhere but I can't find it.

[Illustrative screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZhOr.png)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You formula seems correct. What is your apply range? Is it `A2:A10` or more range? If it more range then use a dollar sign `$` to column letter of criteria part of the formula like `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10, $A2)>=2`

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting will highlight duplicates but it will not move them.

If you do a sort, based on that particular column then the duplicates should be sequential. However if you are sorting by a different column then that will control the sorted order.

It is difficult to guess what is happening without some example data, but leading or trailing spaces is a VERY common error here and comes up often on this  stack.\

As an example, you can see duplicates highlighted below:

[image]